# is there any problem if i put GETH/PARITY and webserver in one server?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, parity, cpp-ethereum

my website need to use something about ETH,so i have to setup a geth/parity rpc server.  is there any problem if i set the geth/parity rpc in my webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not, as long as (and this is a general info):

- Your server is able to handle the load
- Basic networking is done right- for instance port number and firewall rules.

EXTRA:

I used the cloud for a production-grade financial service. During the development, I had everything running on the same instance and things were perfect. But once the project starts getting bigger, you want to have modularity and some sort of fault tolerance and testing. In the final production version, I had an instance dedicated to Parity, Geth (on different networks), and wrote a little REST API service running on these instances. The main application was running on another instance and talking to these via API requests. The added benefit was:

- If something fell apart, everything else was still intact.
- Proper testing.
- Well defined firewall rules.
- Extensibility (You can let your 'premium' client have direct access to fast access to the node itself, etc.)
- Sanity of thought when building something complex.

Comment: @liunliun No worries. Welcome to the community!

Comment: thanks again Mr dave, and i have another question ,can you help me to solve it? thanks!https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62057/how-to-get-the-real-balance-of-eth-by-eth-getbalance